# How can i verify if there are duplicate header values in the response in Postman

Tags: json, header, response, postman

I want to verify if the response headers are unique. If the response headers are not uniquye my postman test fails. Because if there are more response header with the same name, then the values are appended and my expect fails.

So I need a postman tests to verify if the response headers are unique. How can i do it?

Comment: Do you think that a particular header might be duplicated or you think that it could be anything?

Comment: I have seen in few of the api requests that the header X-Powered-By gets duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but it's getting the response header keys and saving those as the `headers` variable. It's then doing a `_.uniq` on that value, which creates a new `array` which strips out the duplicates, then sets this as the `uniqueHeaders` variable.

The test expects those 2 variables to be the same, if I've done this right, then the headers should match and the check will pass, if the response headers are duplicated (which really shouldn't be happening anyway) then the check should fail because the `uniqueHeaders` won't match the actual response headers.

```
pm.test("Checks Headers", () => {

    let headers         = _.keys(pm.response.headers.toObject())
    let uniqueHeaders   = _.uniq(_.keys(pm.response.headers.toObject()))

    pm.expect(headers).to.eql(uniqueHeaders)
});
```

I've not tested this and it's a horrible solution for checking duplicates. You can at least maybe use the `pm.response.headers` value and try and use that to get a better working solution.